# Klaviyo and loop thru a custom property

Tags: klaviyo

I have run into an issue, i have en custom property called shipments, this property is containing an array with info for each package with track & trace information..

The issue here is, how do i fetch the array data? have tried the following

`{% for package in person|lookup:"shipments" %}{{ package }} {% endfor %}` but nothing is getting printed…

The raw data looks like this

```
{"Ordrexxxxx":[{"dropPoint":"Selected Droppoint","trackingCode":"000000000","trackingUrl":"https://gls-group.eu/DK/da/find-pakke?match=0000000000","shipper":"GLS Droppint","amount":1}]
```